# Three20 “pull down to update”: How to change the text and datetime format?

Tags: iphone, ios, refresh, three20, drag

I'm using a TTTableViewController with a TTURLRequestModel and implemented the "Drag to refresh" feature with these lines in my ViewController:

```
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
    return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

What is the right way to change the displayed text? Is it possible to change the arrow-icon too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, the cleanest way to do it, is to extend both `TTTableHeaderDragRefreshView` and `TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate` to your own classes and override the`- (void)setStatus:(TTTableHeaderDragRefreshStatus)status` private function.

You can "hack" this change by changing the value of three20 localized strings and the update arrow in the Three20.Bundle file.